# Useful example of ls -b, --escape

Tags: command-line, ls

I'm new to Ubuntu and I'm learning the `ls` arguments.

I've tested the `-b, --escape` arguments `(print C-style escapes for nongraphic characters)` but I haven't found an useful example of how use it.

I've created a file with the name `\*\?\¿\º\ª\?\¿\&\%\$\·SpecialCharacterfile.txt` using `touch`, but when I use `ls` or `ls -b` it lists the same.

```
*?¿ºª?¿&%$·SpecialCharacterfile.txt
```

I use Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

Comment: I think this question is a useful example: https://superuser.com/q/1184001/326546

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All of your characters are graphic (they have visible glyphs). Try a filename containing whitespace and invisible characters:

```
$ touch $'\n\t\b\a\b'
$ ls -b
\n\t\b\a\b
$ echo *


$ printf "%q\n" *
$'\n'$'\t'$'\b'$'\a'$'\b'
```

An actual useful example where the output would be tricky otherwise: filenames that accidentally had the `\r` character inserted in them because DOS file endings got in the way somewhere in the middle of an operation:

```
$ od -c file-list 
0000000   s   o   m   e   -   f   i   l   e   .   t   x   t  \r  \n
0000017
$ xargs -a file-list touch
$ ls -b
\n\t\b\a\b  file-list  some-file.txt\r
```

I have actually seen this in some post on U&L. Personally, I'd usually use `ls -q` for copy-pasting to the command-line itself:

```
$ ls -q
''$'\n\t\b\a\b'  ' '   file-list  'some-file.txt'$'\r'
```

The default behaviour in newer versions of `ls` is `ls -q` for interactive usage: [Why is 'ls' suddenly wrapping items with spaces in single quotes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/258679/70524)

Comment: Huh wow! ls -q might make it safe to actually parse ls output in shell scripts.

Comment: @Joshua If you have `ls -q` then you have at least one scripting language other than shell, which means you have the option of _not writing a shell script_, which will always be the right choice for anything complicated enough that `ls -q` seems like it would be useful.

Comment: @zwol: How does existence of `ls -q` imply availability of a non-shell script language?

Comment: @R.. Not actually sure, but perhaps the assumption goes that the only systems currently deploying an `ls` with a `-q` flag are systems which field some other scripting interpreter.

Comment: @Joshua Most of the time shell globbing allowed for safe iteration over a list of files anyway. But, if you needed `ls`, extensive care always allowed for safe parsing of `ls` output. In fact, I wrote a very portable shell polyfil for an `esceval` command, which prints a portably shell-quoted version of each argument, located at https://github.com/mentalisttraceur/esceval (shell polyfill is in the `sh` directory, with a C version for performance). `esceval *` gets you the filenames that safely `eval` as their originals. With extreme care, this is enough to handle `ls` output properly.

Comment: @R.. The general observation is that, of all the things that might get you out of dealing with the legacy (not even POSIX) shell environment, `/usr/bin/perl` is the most likely to be available. It shipped with systems that didn't provide Bash, for instance. I do not actually have hard evidence for this but it seems overwhelmingly likely that any system that provides GNU Coreutils (`-q` with the behavior shown is a GNUism; it does something else on \*BSD) would also have Perl and probably also other languages in the same weight class.

Answer (score 6):

Example I found myself

```
$ touch "Hello This is my file"
$ ls
Hello This is my file
```

With `-b` option

```
$ ls -b
Hello\ This\ is\ my\ file
```

Isn't the 2nd one better when I want to use the output somewhere else in my code?

Answer (score 4):

The way you created the files was probably by directly pasting the test. To create files with backslash escapes you need to use `$'...'` type of quoting.

Thus creating files should be:

```
$ touch one$'\n'two  three$'\t'four
```

And the  `ls -b` will show us their representation:

```
$ ls -b                                                    
one\ntwo  three\tfour
```

While default `ls` will not:

```
$ ls
one?two  three?four
```

Note, that having backslash escapes in files can break your scripts, [hence one should never parse ls](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjLhLa2kr_SAhVC2IMKHa3kA-EQFggjMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmywiki.wooledge.org%2FParsingLs&usg=AFQjCNEbsLAlA5MndgULyIuQVf2hqnAEWg&sig2=1aO_qqjLnSQRmGh3zZsIIw). And exactly the main purpose for `ls -b` - to see what filenames have and potentially troubleshoot them.

Comment: +1 for the explicit explanation of how to create files with nongraphic characters

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [muru's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/889751/527764) which explains that none of the characters in your filename are non-graphic, I will point out that your filename does not actually contain any backslashes (the shell removes them when running the command of course)

If it did, `-b` would cause them to be printed with escapes:

```
$ touch 'hi\(zanna' hi\(zanna
$ ls
hi(zanna  hi\(zanna
$ ls -b
hi(zanna  hi\\(zanna
```

Comment: Yep, and this is why quoting is important in shell. Unquoted variables/strings are subject to shell expansion and backslash escape removal.